# Does installing more CPUs (Intel) than indicated by "Max CPU Configuration" prevent all cores from being used?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, central-processing-unit, intel, multi-core

I am looking at a server that has 4 physical processors, the Intel documentation indicates they are 6 core processors but this WMI query

```
WMIC CPU Get NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors /Format:List
```

yields the following

```
NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=4
```

The product documentation indicates that the MAX CPU Configuration = 2

Comment: Exactly what is the hardware and operating system?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2, Intel Xeon CPU E5-2640 @ 2.5GHz, 32 GB Ram. Not sure of the make and model of the physical server.

Comment: I assume it's the Standard Edition, not the Enterprise Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the "Max CPU Configuration" is meant to say that the CPU can be configured two work with X other physical CPU's on your motherboard.

Not having to do with how many cores of one physical CPU you can have configured to run.

Comment: funny story, it was a virtual relaying the host's information. Thanks for the answer though.